# ActionMapping in Action class of Struts2

Tags: struts2

I am developing an application on Struts2(2.5.16). I came across a situation where my action class needs to know its action name(defined in struts.xml). In struts1, we can achieve this by using **mapping.getPath()**. How can we achieve this in struts2?

my struts.xml:

```
    <action name="testAction" class="action.TestAction">
        <result name="success">/success.jsp</result>
        <result name="error">/error.jsp</result>
    </action>
```

I want to get "**testAction**" in my struts2 action class.

Thanks,
Sunil

Comment: What is the reason? In general an action should not need to know what it is called, for a variety of reasons. Perhaps there's a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the ActionContext?

```
String actionName = ActionContext.getContext().getName();
```